# jQuery and/or PHP location finder: zip code and city/state

Tags: php, jquery, geolocation, location, zipcode

I'm looking to auto-populate a form input textarea with the user's city, state. I also need the zip code to pass with the form. I don't need a map.

Any suggestions? (I prefer jQuery and/or PHP.)

**UPDATE** -
I discovered this little js to get the city, state, latitude, longitude, area code, etc... except it doesn't get the zip. Probably because a lot of cities have multiple zips. But all I need is one zip from the city... it doesn't matter which one, because I'm grabbing data within a 50 mile radius. So is there anyway to take this script below and find a zip from the location based on the data that it returns.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="Javascript"> 
document.write("Welcome to our visitors from "+geoplugin_city()+", "+geoplugin_region()+", Area code = "+geoplugin_areaCode()+", Latitude = "+geoplugin_latitude()+geoplugin_areaCode()+", Longitude = "+geoplugin_longitude()); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: [GeoPlugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/examples)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GeoLite City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) to convert the user's IP into the City, State Zip

Comment: Know anything about geoplugin? How to get zip from area code?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to do this without server-side code, which is kind of obvious considering the potential security risk. What you can do however, is make a request to some server-side script and have it parse the user's IP, but there are certain pitfalls with that - 1.) city/state are all you can get, and 2.) Users could be using a proxy and on top of that, IPs sometimes aren't accurate.

There's also the HTML5 Geolocation API: http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: The page is already php driven, so a server side script is fine. Also, I'm not too worried about proxies or the script failing because the user can always type in the city.

Comment: the link above does not work seamlessly. I get a message in firefox that htm5demos want to know your location. You do not want to prompt user with these questions

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1) server-side using php library for geolocation based on the ip (works only if the geodata for the ip is entered correctly by the ISP) and insert the data wherever you like

2) use google maps' [geocoding service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding)  to dynamically retrieve the info you need.

p.s. my favorite way is #2 offers much more flexibility.

Comment: I updated the posting. Do you know how to get a zip from latitude/longitude or area code?